# How to assign System.Drawing.Color to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ColorFormat

Tags: c#, excel, colors, system.drawing

Sample code as follow,

```
Chart.SerialsCollection(1).Point(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Return an error. Cannot implicitly convert type, one is a Struct, the other is ColorFormat.

ForeColor.RGB is **Int** type, I can only get 3 ints from Color.Red.R, Color.Red.G and Color.Red.B.  How to assign the color I want to ForeColor property?

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786008/how-to-convert-from-system-drawing-color-to-excel-colorformat-in-c-change-comm

Comment: ColorTranslator.ToOle works fine as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786008/how-to-convert-from-system-drawing-color-to-excel-colorformat-in-c-change-comm).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try [RGB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.chartsheet.chartstyle.aspx) property `ForeColor.RGB`

E.g.

```
Chart.SerialsCollection(1).Point(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = System.Drawing.Color.Red.ToArgb();
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried this, it can pass compiling, but the color is not correct. Color.Red is shown as a different color.  I think it's because RGB and ARGB is two different color system, right?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, use [ColorTranslator.ToOle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.toole(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Chart.SerialsCollection(1).Point(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);
```

Or, entering the `RGB` values:

```
Chart.SerialsCollection(1).Point(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
```

Some additional information, so I'm not just repeating the comments:

`ForeColor.RGB` can be represented in Hex as `0xBBGGRR` ([source](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/snippets/rgb)). Knowing that, you could create the following function:

```
public int Color_to_RGB(Color color) {
    return (color.B << 16) | (color.G << 8) | Color.R;
}
```

Use:

```
Chart.SerialCollection(1).Point(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Color_to_RGB(Color.Red);
```

The reason `ToArgb()`, used in the other answer, does not work because its Hex representation is `0xAARRGGBB`