# How to convert from System.Drawing.Color to Excel.ColorFormat in C#? Change comment color

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins, system.drawing.color

I'm developing a vsto addin for Excel, and I'm trying to change the color to the comments in Excel.

This is the code that I have:

```
Excel.Range activeCell = _application.ActiveCell;
activeCell.AddComment("some text"));
activeCell.Comment.Shape.Fill.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

The exception I'm getting is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Color' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ColorFormat'

I cannot find how to make a conversion between the two formats.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518048/how-to-assign-system-drawing-color-to-microsoft-office-interop-excel-colorformat).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use [`ColorTranslator.ToOle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.toole(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int oleColor = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);
activeCell.Comment.Shape.Fill.BackColor.RGB = oleColor;
```

Comment: The question is asking to convert the other way around, so this answer is not correct... I wonder why the upvoter didn't both reading the question either... ha, maybe you have a clone

Comment: Thanks @HariPrasad, It solved my problem. I couldn't find the answer anywhere else!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
activeCell.Comment.Shape.Fill.BackColor = XlRgbColor.rgbRed;
```

Or this(EDIT: False):

```
activeCell.Comment.Shape.Fill.BackColor.RGB =  Color.FromRgb(255,0,0);
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work. `Color.FromRgb` will still return a `Color` object, and `RGB` is not going to accept that. If it did, then OP could just use `Color.Red` as per original attempt.